# Question about derivation of vector potential

Tags: electromagnetism

In a book, it says

$$\vec{A}=-\frac{2}{3c^2}\sum e \dot {\vec{v}}$$

Then it says because $$\vec{H}=\textrm{curl}~\vec{A}$$ and since $\vec{A}$ **doesn't depend on the coordinates explicitly**, $\vec{H}$ is zero.

My question is I can always express it as

$$\vec{A}=-\frac{2}{3c^2}\sum e \ddot {\vec{x}}$$

Isn't that it will depends on coordinate then? This is a concept I have been confused with for a long time. Can anyone help clarify? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you describe the situation and what is v?

Comment: Thank you for your response! It was talking about radiation damping. It expands the retarded potential to higher order term. This term is the higher order term. And it tries to say this term has no effect on H. v is the velocity and $\vec{v}=\dot{\vec{x}}$

Answer (score 0):

**Depending on the *time derivative* of a variable does not constitute depending on the variable itself.**

This is because the time derivative of a variable does not itself depend on the variable: **$\dot{\vec{x}}$ does not depend on $\vec{x}$.**

Mathematical explanation (thanks to HYW):

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\right)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dx}\right)=\frac{1}{\mathrm dt}=0$$

The derivative of $\dot{x}$ with respect to $x$ is 0: **$\dot{\vec{x}}$ does not depend on $\vec{x}$.**

Physical explanation:

If you take a snapshot of a moving object, you would have information about its position, but no information at all about how fast it's going. An infinite number of objects could all be located at a position $\vec{r}$, but they could still all be going at different velocities.

Conversely, say you know an object is moving with a velocity $\vec{v}$. Where should such an object be located? Well, there's nothing stopping us from placing it at a position $\vec{r_1}$, or at another position $\vec{r_2}$. The object could be going at a velocity $\vec{v}$ regardless of its position: **velocity is independent of position.**

Comment: Thank you for explaining the physics! After reading yours, I realized that I should also have been able to derive this mathematically. dv/dx=d(dx/dt)/dx = d(dx/dx)/dt=d1/dt=0. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, that explanation is much simpler. I think it's best if you post it as a separate answer and mark it as accepted; I'll upvote the answer, too, for the brevity!

Comment: No, I didn't mean mine is simpler than yours. Yours gives physical insight, which is more important. It was yours to trigger me think deeper how to prove mathematically and I write it down to remind myself.

Comment: Hmm. Although for other people looking for answers here, one quick look at the mathematical answer might be all it takes. Maybe I'll try to edit your comment into the answer and credit you.